# Skip binding ID but return it as a response

Tags: mongodb, rest, go, go-gin

I have a Person struct as follows:

```
type Person struct {
  ID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
  HomeAddress Address `bson:"home_address" json:"home_address"`
  Pets []*struct {
    ID string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Species string `json:"species"`
  } `json:"items"`
}
```

The person's ID is generated automatically in mongodb. A person may have pets with ID that is generated using UUID in the backend. So the JSON sent by user shouldn't include the ID of Person and ID of every pet.
I use this struct when receiving the json sent by the user, saving the data to my mongodb, and return it as a response in my handler as follows:

```
PersonPostResponse struct {
  models.Person
  ServerTime time.Time `json:"server_time"`
  EditFlag bool `json:"edit_locked"`
}

// handler of POST /person

return func(c *gin.Context) {
  newPerson := models.Person{}
  if err := c.shouldBindJSON(&newPerson); err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    return
  }
  if _, err := (*repo).SavePersonData(c, &newPerson); err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    return
  }
  c.JSON(http.StatusOK, PersonPostResponse{newPerson, time.Now(), false})
}
```

The problem is, when I try to send the JSON with Person ID of 24 chars, it is accepted and saved to the mongodb. I tried putting the suggestions from this link https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/pull/1733

```
ID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"id,omitempty" json:"-" binding:"-"`
```

but the POST response doesn't include the ID of the newly created Person as a result.

How do I skip ID of Person and ID of pets when binding but return it as a response?
Is it not a good practice to use the same struct for 3 different purposes? In reality I have 17 JSON fields and I'm not sure if its good that I rewrite them 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled in several ways. One way is to split the structure to support different views of it:

```
// Use this variant as the Person without ID
type Person struct {
 // All person fields, except the  ID
}

// Use this variant for DB operations and when you need ID
type DBPerson struct {
  ID primitive.ObjectId
  Person `bson:",inline"`
}
```

Another and sometimes simpler way to deal with it is that after binding the user, manually clear the ID you received:

```
  newPerson := models.Person{}
  if err := c.shouldBindJSON(&newPerson); err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    return
  }
  newPerson.ID=primitive.NilObjectID
```

Or, you can also given an error if it is nonempty.